# Running program in foreach loop with arguments

Tags: powershell, foreach

When running a program in a foreach loop in powershell, how can I add multiple arguments? The code below does not work.

```
gci -Recurse -Include *.pdf | %{"C:\Program Files (x86)\someApp\test.exe" -ci jpg -gi jpg -mi fax + $_.fullname}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Do you get an error? Undesired output? No output at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `&` sign to call the executable:

```
gci -Recurse -Include *.pdf | %{&"C:\Program Files (x86)\someApp\test.exe" -ci jpg -gi jpg -mi fax + $_.fullname}
```

Comment: Guessing that you would need to handle this `fax + $_.fullname` since using the command operator would not interpret this as intended. Would seem the op is trying to use "fax" as name prefix. As is I think it would be taken as 3 different arguments.

Comment: Yes, I tested locally by invoking notepad and used just `$_.fullname` as an argument. In the case of the example above, that `fax + $_.fullname` would need to be fixed, however I don't know what -mi is and what is required.